# Rails select tag option not being selected (using float data)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Invoice model I have an attribute called 'discount'. It's a float value, usually in increments of 5% (0, 5, 10, 15...). I use float and not simply integer because of future-proofing.

So anyway, in my form I populate a drop-down select box with values ranging from 0 to 50, but when I edit a previously saved invoice, the form select method does not select the recorded amount.

Form:

```
f.select :discount, options_for_select((0..50).step(5).map {|x| ["#{ x }%", x.to_f]}), {}, {:style => 'padding-right:0; margin-right:0', :tabindex => -1}
```

I've tried this with just `x` instead of `x.to_f`, I've also tried `'%.2f' % x`, but no matter what format I put it in, it won't automatically set the correct % discount option.

Resulting HTML:

```
<select id="invoice_discount" name="invoice[discount]" style="padding-right:0; margin-right:0" tabindex="-1" data-cip-id="cIPJQ342845641">
    <option value="0.0">0%</option>
    <option value="5.0">5%</option>
    <option value="10.0">10%</option>
    <option value="15.0">15%</option>
    <option value="20.0">20%</option>
    <option value="25.0">25%</option>
    <option value="30.0">30%</option>
    <option value="35.0">35%</option>
    <option value="40.0">40%</option>
    <option value="45.0">45%</option>
    <option value="50.0">50%</option>
</select>
```

Checking the current invoice's discount...

`@invoice.discount` yields `15.0`

So I know the data's there for the form to use but it just isn't selecting the option tag and I figure it has something to do with the fact that the discount is in float format but what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
f.select :discount, (0..50).step(5).map{|x| ["#{ x }%", x.to_f]}, {}, {:style => 'padding-right:0; margin-right:0', :tabindex => -1}
```

When use the options_for_select, you have to pass it the current value.